# Axis2 - Information Leakage Prevention

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, apache-axis, owasp

What is the easiest way to either configure Axis2 or extend the message listener to PREVENT any and all information regarding system from returning to the calling client?

An example of what I'm trying to prevent is as follows: Someone sends an improper soap request with some weird stuff in the header and the server responds:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Wed, 19 Nov 2014 13:12:34 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)
Connection: close
Content-Length: 465
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
... 
<faultstring>javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DOCTYPE is not allowed</faultstring>
```

What is the best way to prevent all of that information from being delivered back to the client?  The glassfish messages can be turned off in GlassFish as answered below.  I should have been more specific I want to set it up so that any and all exceptions never reach the client.  I want to somehow force axis2 to use a generic message instead of returning an Exception.  Is it possible to do this with Axis2?

Comment: Specifically what information do you want to suppress?

Comment: Assuming you want to suppress the `X-Powered-By` header, you would do that by configuring your web server or web container, in your case it is Glassfish.

Comment: I assume I can edit this somewhere in the glassfish admin config page?  I would like to remove as much of that 'debug' information as possible so that if someone is trying to get information they do not see that.  In addition I would like to create a custom catch all error message to return if someone sends a bad soap request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a

> -Dproduct.name="".

in your JVM Option for suppressing the X-Powered-By

Comment: The above worked great for Glassfish info removal (Which I edited via Glassfish gui console as suggested by Panko above).  The secondary answer which was the challenge was setting up mod_jk to use server error messages and then specifying a custom error message.  Now I can get the following returned:
`HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 05 Jan 2015 20:30:47 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 36
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Your request could not be processed.`